# How are the impersonal "доводилось" and "приходилось" nuanced?

Tags: выбор-слова

In conversation, I just said this –  and the sentence with "доводилось" sarcastically:

> Не зря говорят, что японцы трудоголики и все такое, но... он в самом деле заходит слишком далеко. Как-то не **доводилось** мне встречать человека, в котором было бы столько страсти, что  он вкалывал бы аж на смерть.  Низкий ему поклон.

I'm wondering how the use of "приходилось" would have stacked up against "доводилось". Does "приходилось" sound somewhat ambiguous, given its another impersonal usage in the sense of "have to"?

> Как-то не **приходилось** мне встречать человека, в котором ...

Answer (score 4):

**"Доводилось"** and **"приходилось"** are often synonymous, but there is one minor nuance.
**"Доводилось"** has a connotation **"had a chance to"**,  while **"приходилось"** has the connotation **'had to ...'**

You might say:

> Мне **доводилось** бывать на приемах у Королевы

but you wouldn't want to say:

> Мне **приходилось** бывать на приемах у Королевы

On the contrary, you'd rather say:

> Мне **приходилось** заниматься скучной, однообразной работой.

than

> Мне **доводилось** заниматься скучной, однообразной работой.

Answer (score 0):

In the meaning you gave these two words are fully interchangeable. **Доводилось** seems to be a less frequent synonim, but please, do use it.

**Приходилось** has also the meaning of "I had to", "I was forced/compelled to":

> **Мне пришлось вернуться домой за забытыми вещами.
>
>   Мне приходилось не раз возвращаться домой за вещами, которые мои дети забыли, собираясь в
>   школу.**

You can use **доводилось** in these sentences as well, but it will imply just the fact that you have the experience of returning home to pick up some belongings. Whereas **приходилось** also means you were not happy with that. :)

But in your examples there is no negarive connotation, because they describe a situation in which the speaker was not involved, he or she is just an observer.

Насмерть is an adjective, it's one word here.